# Trying To Make My App Universal

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cordova, universal

I have two HTML files on my `www` folder using the PhoneGap framework. The iPhone/iPod one(`/mobile/index.html`) and the iPad one(`/index.html`). So I'm using this code at my `AppDelegate.m`:

```
+ (NSString*) startPage
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        return @"index.html";
    } else {
        return @"mobile/index.html";
    }
}
```

And edited my `Targeted Device Family` to `iPhone/iPad`.

But for some reason it won't work. When I put it on my iPad it still put the application on compatibility mode. What should I do?

Comment: Nathan, I am trying to do the exact same thing, I dropped this function into my SanAntonioAppDelegate.m file and now the app crashes onload.  I don't see any other function trying to call this startPage function. Could you please explain a little more where you put this in and a bit on how to get it working?

Comment: Strange, maybe it's your Xcode version. When I used this function I was using Xcode 3 with the iOS 4 SDK. I haven't tried this on my new iOS environment

Comment: well where exactly did you put it? i'm a noob to phonegap meaning i'm even more of a noob for this objective c stuff, how/where did you put this in?

Comment: You put this on the `AppDelegate.m` file that is on the Objective-C sources folder in your project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

- Select your target.
- Click on the Project menu & choose "Upgrade Current Target for iPad."
- In the dialog box that comes up, you're given two choices. Select "One Universal Application."

Not sure that's what you're missing.  But, if you haven't done it yet, it couldn't hurt.

Comment: That option is grey(disabled) **:/**

Comment: Make sure you have the target selected when you click on the Project menu.  If the target isn't selected the option will be disabled.

Comment: But, if you do have the target selected and the option is disabled, it may be that you have effectively already done this.  The option does not come up on the apps that I already have working on the iPad.  Sorry, if this isn't the problem, I'm not sure what you're missing.